# Error 405 multiples peticiones livewire

Tags: php, fetch, laravel-livewire

Estoy teniendo problemas al usar livewire, el evento fetch que se dispara por carácter ingresado a un input wire:model se manda llamar tantas veces que el host de cpanel manda un error 405, ¿como hago para que esto no suceda?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega lo que ya has intentado, revisa [ask].

Comment: Es muy simple de solucionar, edita y mejora tu pregunta con detalles y te respondemos

Comment: Necesitamos detalles por ejemplo ocurre alguna validación con que el usuario escriba en el input o tienes ligada esa funcionalidad a algún otro evento en otro elemento como el click en un botón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos, gracias encentré la respuesta al problema que estaba buscando comparto la liga https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding. Básicamente era la forma de envió de datos del formulario, después de usar wire:model.defer se agrega el "defer" para no mandar los datos de un input[number, text] o textarea que son normalmente de texto abierto.